# Overloaded method resolution at runtime and how type promotion works?

Tags: java, methods, int, double, overloading

```
package arunjava;

public class sample3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box25 b1 = new Box25();
        Box25 b2 = new Box25();


        b1.Dimension(25, 32, 65);
        b2.Dimension(25, 45, 62);

        System.out.println("volume is" + b1.volume());
        System.out.println("volume is" + b2.volume());

        b1.Dimension(4, 6, 8);
        b2.Dimension(6, 8, 4);

        System.out.println("volume is" + b1.vol());
        System.out.println("volume is" + b2.vol());
    }
}

class Box25 {
    double height, width, depth;

    int height1, width1, depth1;

    public void Dimension(double height, double width, double depth) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.depth = depth;
    }

    public void Dimension(int height1, int width1, int depth1) {
        this.height1 = height1;
        this.width1 = width1;
        this.depth1 = depth1;
    }

    double volume() {
        return height * depth * width;
    }

    int vol() {
        return height1 * depth1 * width1;
    }
}
```

I had created the above program in my Java tutorial. The problem is that I am not able to compute the volume of the box which has the double datatype.

The programme result shows the following:

```
volume is0.0
volume is0.0
volume is192
volume is192
```

Secondly, I am confused about the Java concept of method overloading, as I know that in method overloading we can use the same method name with different parameters but as I created the volume method, I had to modify the name of the methods(volume,vol), so as to overload the volume method and get the answer. Why is it like that?

Comment: In reference to overloading `volume()` -- *as i know that in method overloading we can use the same method name with different parameters* -- key word being parameters, you can't overload methods by changing their return types.

Comment: The reason is obvious: You pass integers to the constructors, so the double values are never set.  They are always zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following lines invokes

```
b1.Dimension(25, 32, 65);
b1.Dimension(4, 6, 8);
```

invokes method `public void Dimension(int height1, int width1, int depth1)` because the literal's 25, 32 and 65 are treated of type `int`

So, the fields `height, width, depth` of class `Box25` have default values 0.0 hence the output you get is 0.

There are various ways you can fix the problem, by invoking appropriate method

**Approach 1:**

```
b1.Dimension((double)25, (double)32, (double)65);
b1.Dimension((double)4, (double)6, (double)8);
```

**Approach 2:**

```
double h = 25, w = 32, d = 65;
b1.Dimension(25, 32, 65);
```

**Approach 3:**

```
b1.Dimension(25.0, 32.0, 65.0);
b1.Dimension(4.0, 6.0, 8.0);
```

**Why are the `int` arguments passed, not promoted to `double`?**

- At runtime, the resolution first happens by exact match of argument types
- If the matching types are found, then the method with exact matched arguments is invoked
- If there no exact match of arguments, then the types are promoted to next higher type and if there is a match, then that method is invoked.

**Example 1:**

```
public class OverloadingDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        OverloadingDemo obj = new OverloadingDemo();
        obj.sayHello(10);
    }

    public void sayHello(double x) {
        System.out.println("Hello double  " + x);
    }

}
```

**Output:** Hello double  10.0

**Reason:** Since there is no matching method for value 10 (which is of type `int`), it is promoted to `long`. As there is no matching method which accepts `long` argument, it is promoted to `double`. Now that there is a method with accepts `double` argument, it is invoked.

**Example 2:**

```
public class OverloadingDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        OverloadingDemo obj = new OverloadingDemo();
        obj.sayHello(10);
    }

    public void sayHello(int x) {
        System.out.println("Hello int  " + x);
    }

    public void sayHello(double x) {
        System.out.println("Hello double  " + x);
    }

}
```

**Output:** Hello int  10

**Reason:** Since there is a matching method for value 10 (which is of type `int`), it is invoked.

**Example 3:**

```
public class OverloadingDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        OverloadingDemo obj = new OverloadingDemo();
        obj.sayHello(10);
    }

    public void sayHello(long x) {
        System.out.println("Hello long  " + x);
    }

    public void sayHello(double x) {
        System.out.println("Hello double  " + x);
    }

}
```

**Output:** Hello long  10

**Reason:** Since there is no matching method for value 10 (which is of type `int`), it is promoted to `long`. Now that there is a method with accepts `long` argument, it is invoked.

Comment: Why cast? You could use decimal numbers

Comment: Yes, thats another approach. I was demonstrating how to invoke appropriate method. Updated the answer

Comment: as you suggested the above approches, is it necessary to declare as 25.0  or 25d explicitly ? why is the automatic type promotion concept not working over here? i mean to say that when i call the double volume method why don't the arguments automatically get promoted to double

Comment: @VijayKannan, good question! I have updated the answer with more examples, that can help you understand overloading method resolution at runtime

Answer (score 1):

I think having two sets of attributes is wrong.  Here's how I'd write it.

```
public class Box {

   private final double l, h, w;

   public Box(double length, double height, double width) {
      this.l = length; 
      this.h = height;
      this.w = width;
   }

   public double getVolume() { return this.l*this.h*this.w; }
}
```

As written, there's nothing to stop you from entering negative or zero dimensions.  Does that make sense?  What should you do to guarantee sensible values?

If you insist on keeping your class, here's how you can fix the problem:

```
class Box25
{
    double height,width,depth;

    int height1,width1,depth1;

    public void Dimension(double height, double width, double depth)
    {
        this.height=height;
        this.width=width;
        this.depth=depth;

        this.height1 = (int) height;
        this.width1 = (int) width;
        this.depth1= (int) depth;

    }

    public void Dimension(int height1, int width1, int depth1)
    {
        this.height1=height1;
        this.width1=width1;
        this.depth1=depth1;

        this.height = height1;
        this.width = width1;
        this.depth = depth1;    
    }

      double volume()
    {
        return height*depth*width;
    }
     int vol()
    {
        return height1*depth1*width1;
    }

}
```

You needed to set all variables.

Now both methods will return what you want.  I'd still argue that your way is unnecessary.

Comment: yes @Vijay Kannan ... the suggested way would be to assign values from constructor like this instead of `Dimension` method

Answer (score 0):

specify that it is double value like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Box25 b1=new Box25();
        Box25 b2=new Box25();


        b1.Dimension(25d, 32d, 65d);
        b2.Dimension(25d, 45d, 62d);
        ...
        ...
}
```

**Output**

```
volume is52000.0
volume is69750.0
volume is192
volume is192
```